# Firestore Blocked users rule

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I've been searching for an answer for this for a time now,

Simply I have an Android app, this app allows users to write or read to/from the database which is Firestore

I have a collection named `BlockList` which meant to hold the users `uid` as the document name and a field value named `userUid`, the purpose of this collection is to deny any write "only" request for users who misbehave in the application. 
In other words, I am looking for firestore rule to allow the users in `BlockList` to read **only** what's shared in the application and **deny** all the write operations they try to make.

I've already tested these rules but it doesn't work, **it doesn't allow any read or write operation even if the user is not on the `BlockList`**

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
   function isBlackListed() {
      return exists(/databases/$(database)/BlockList/$(request.auth.uid))
    }
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null && !isBlackListed();
    }
  }
}


----------


rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
         allow write: if !exists(/databases/$(database)/documents/BlockList/$(request.auth.uid))

  }
}
```

**Update**

Thanks to Marc's answer I managed to get everything right
**Working rule**

```
 match /Posts/{document=**}{
      allow write :if !exists(/databases/$(database)/documents/BlockList/$(request.auth.uid))
      allow read :if request.auth.uid != null;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

dont know if i get your problem right and it would have been helpful to have seen your rules which you tried so far, but i think this should work:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      // Make sure a write to all documents is only allowed when
      // the current user has no document in BlockList collection
      allow write: if !exists(/databases/$(database)/documents/BlockList/$(request.auth.uid))
    }
  }
}
```

I have tested this with my firestore instance and it looks ok to me. Of course you most likely will need to specify the documents better instead of the wildcard match.

It doesnt matter what data you have in the BlockList documents as long there is a document with the userUid as doc name in the BlockList collection.

I have created two documents (which represent users) in the BlockList collection.

[image: two users in BlockList]

Now i try to write to my tournaments table which has the mentioned security.rule via Simulator "Update" method (with auth credentials supplied of course)

[image: blocked by rule because user is in BlockList]

When removing the user "8Zvq1fpWl2S0h1t7bIxNoxDcucn1" from BlockList and use Simulator again, i get:

[image: allowed by second rule]

Summary: to me it looks working quite well.

Comment: Thank you, I've tried it but it doesn't work, please see my updated question I've included what I tried and didn't work

Comment: i really created the stuff on my side and it worked. Did both ways of testing if the rule works. How did you tested it? With the firestore simulator? Thats what i did.

Comment: I didn't test it with the simulator, I tested it with a real Android device

Comment: then its most likely an Auth issue. I edited my post for clarification,

Comment: Ok, So after I saw your clarification images I edited the rules and wrote a specific rule for every collection instead of the wildcard as you mentioned and for the collections I wanted to deny the blocked user from writing to it, I used your answer, however, I had to add a line for reading permission, and everything worked as intended now, Thanks. I'd give you +1 for your answer but sadly I didn't make enough repetitions till now

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to solve this issue, here is a strategy based off of what you have already (collection of user documents that include uids of users that you want to block from write access).

**Frontend Solution**

When a user authenticates with your app, send a request to see if that uid is also in the `BlockList` collection. If it does exist, set a boolean flag in your app that all db calls reference before allowing the call to execute.

**Backend Solution**

Since nothing is secure in the frontend, you'll want to couple the frontend validation with backend security.

The changes the user is attempting to make can be staged in a 'trigger document' that a cloud function in the backend then executes `onWrite`.

Your cloud function can then query the `BlockList` collection to see if the uid is indeed among the collection, and if so then send back an error (or not) to the client while preventing any writes.

Answer (score 0):

If the number of people in the blocked list is low, you can use the following solution of manually blocking off people in the rules.

```
rules_version = '2';

service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
        function isBanned(uid) {
                return uid in [
        // List of banned naughty peope!
        "uid-1....DLZV2",
        "uid-2....OB0w2"
        ];
        }
        allow read, write: if request.auth != null && !isBanned(request.auth.uid);
    }
  }
}
```